# Are the two music notes a reference?

Tags: music, idolish7

In episode 2 of Idolish7, 11:08 the following two music notes appeared as the background where two main character talks in chibi form. The character on the right is embarrassed and walks away. Is the background music score a reference to something?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The 2 notes (G D) are read as [*sore*](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%B6%E3%82%8C)**, meaning "that" in Japanese. This coincides with Nagi's dialog, "***sore** o shinpai to iu no de wa?*", emphasizing whether Iori was actually worried about Tsumugi.

The last symbol "D.C." is [*da capo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_capo) which means "from the beginning". This *might* imply "to go back to handing the fliers", which was what they were doing currently.